# Do not show path to sub menu items in breadcrumb

Tags: php, drupal, drop-down-menu, drupal-7, hook-menu

I would like to hide the path to sub menu item which is shown in the breadcrumb once you request a page by clicking the sub menu.

Here is the code I am using to create a menu item and three sub menu items:

```
    $items['what-to-expect'] = array(
        'title' => t('What To Expect'),
        'page callback' => 'pvmf_layout_what_to_expect',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'weight' => 1,
        'expanded' => TRUE
      );
      $items['what-to-expect/0'] = array(
        'title' => t('Local Event'),
        'page callback' => 'pvmf_layout_what_to_expect_0',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'weight' => 0
      );
      $items['what-to-expect/1'] = array(
        'title' => t('Online Event'),
        'page callback' => 'pvmf_layout_what_to_expect_1',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'weight' => 1
      );
      $items['what-to-expect/2'] = array(
        'title' => t('ONE Presenters'),
        'page callback' => 'pvmf_layout_what_to_expect_2',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'weight' => 2
      );
```

Here is what I see:
[image]

After I change the `type` in definition here is the code I am getting:

```
$items['what-to-expect'] = array(
    'title' => t('What To Expect'),
    'page callback' => 'pvmf_layout_what_to_expect',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    'type' => MENU_VISIBLE_IN_TREE,
    'weight' => 1,
    'expanded' => TRUE
  );
  $items['what-to-expect/0'] = array(
    'title' => t('Local Event'),
    'page callback' => 'pvmf_layout_what_to_expect_0',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_VISIBLE_IN_TREE,
    'weight' => 0
  );
  $items['what-to-expect/1'] = array(
    'title' => t('Online Event'),
    'page callback' => 'pvmf_layout_what_to_expect_1',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_VISIBLE_IN_TREE,
    'weight' => 1
  );
  $items['what-to-expect/2'] = array(
    'title' => t('ONE Presenters'),
    'page callback' => 'pvmf_layout_what_to_expect_2',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_VISIBLE_IN_TREE,
    'weight' => 2
  );
```

But breadcrumbs still continue to show. I tried to clear the cache by going to `Configuration` -> `Performance`, but it did not help. What may I miss here?

I checked that `menu.inc` actually contains:

```
/**
 * Menu type -- A "normal" menu item that's shown in menu and breadcrumbs.
 *
 * Normal menu items show up in the menu tree and can be moved/hidden by
 * the administrator. Use this for most menu items. It is the default value if
 * no menu item type is specified.
 */
define('MENU_NORMAL_ITEM', MENU_VISIBLE_IN_TREE | MENU_VISIBLE_IN_BREADCRUMB);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `type => MENU_VISIBLE_IN_TREE` in sub menu items definition so that they are visible only in the menu, not in the breadcrumb.

The flags for the menu item types are defined in `includes/menu.inc`. There we can see that the `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` flag takes its bits from the bitwise OR operation of `MENU_VISIBLE_IN_TREE` and `MENU_VISIBLE_IN_BREADCRUMB`:

```
/**
 * Menu type -- A "normal" menu item that's shown in menu and breadcrumbs.
 *
 * Normal menu items show up in the menu tree and can be moved/hidden by
 * the administrator. Use this for most menu items. It is the default value if
 * no menu item type is specified.
 */
define('MENU_NORMAL_ITEM', MENU_VISIBLE_IN_TREE | MENU_VISIBLE_IN_BREADCRUMB);
```

That means the flag for a `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` not showing in the breadcrumb is `MENU_VISIBLE_IN_TREE`.

Comment: Could you, please, advise what else might be wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Is not it only possible to do this using css? For instance, [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/adminimal_theme/issues/2370669). Thank you once more.

Comment: If you still see these items in the breadcrumb it could be that a custom breadcrumb 
 module like *easy_breadcrumb* is enabled, in this case you would need to check the module configuration. Or it could be that some hardcode in a template file is displaying the breadcrumb regardless of the menu item type, check your template files. Still you can hide it via css but it depends on your active theme (the link you provided refers to a specific theme, @see .adminimal-theme class, so you would need to use the proper selector).